# This model supports sub-batching, but it also requires slicing, which is not possible for sLCWA

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, knowledge-graph

I am using a Compute Farm server to train a knowledge graph model using the ComplEx model from the Pykeen Library. Although the GPU Hardware (I even specified a TeslaP4 with 8GB of ram and only 68M of used memory at the time I requested it) I am using "should" be performant, it is throwing the same error even if I choose a small batch size.

Here is the complete set of parameters

```
    def create_embedding_model(
    self,
    kg_training_loop="slcwa",
    kg_neg_sampler="bernoulli",
    kg_batch_size=128,
    kg_number_epochs=20,
):
    self.kg_logger.info("Starting to train the knowledge graph embedding model...")

    self.kg_embedding_model_pipeline = pipeline(
        training=self.triples_literals_factory,
        testing=self.triples_literals_factory,
        model=self.kg_embedding_model,
        training_kwargs=dict(
            num_epochs=kg_number_epochs,
            use_tqdm=True,
            batch_size=kg_batch_size,
        ),
        evaluation_kwargs=dict(
            use_tqdm=True,
            batch_size=kg_batch_size // 4
            if torch.cuda.is_available()
            else kg_batch_size,
        ),
        negative_sampler=kg_neg_sampler,
        training_loop=kg_training_loop,
        random_seed=self.kg_random_seed,
    )

    self.kg_embedding_initialized_model = embedding_model_pipeline.model

    return self.kg_embedding_initialized_model
```

The error I get is the following

```
------------------

----- stderr -----
2023-07-11 18:05:11,393: knowledge_graph_model_logger - INFO: No saved model available. Creating knowledge graph model...
----- stderr -----
2023-07-11 18:05:11,400: knowledge_graph_model_logger - INFO: Starting to train the knowledge graph embedding model...
----- stderr -----
/home/ml_in_pp/virtualenvs/KG_MEHDI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pykeen/nn/representation.py:369: UserWarning: Directly use Embedding.max_id instead of num_embeddings.
  warnings.warn(f"Directly use {self.__class__.__name__}.max_id instead of num_embeddings.")
----- stderr -----
/home/ml_in_pp/virtualenvs/KG_MEHDI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pykeen/nn/representation.py:375: UserWarning: Directly use Embedding.shape instead of num_embeddings.
  warnings.warn(f"Directly use {self.__class__.__name__}.shape instead of num_embeddings.")
----- stderr -----
INFO:pykeen.training.training_loop:Starting sub_batch_size search for training now...
----- stderr -----
INFO:pykeen.training.training_loop:Even sub_batch_size=1 does not fit in memory with these parameters
----- stderr -----
WARNING:pykeen.training.slcwa:This model supports sub-batching, but it also requires slicing, which is not possible for sLCWA
------------------

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_241976/2969253896.py in <module>
      4     #kg_saved_model_path = os.path.join(my_path, 'saved_models', 'knowledge_graph_model', 'trained_model.pkl'),
      5     kg_saved_model_path = None,
----> 6     logger=knowledge_graph_model_logger,
      7 )

/home/csc-e-in/workspace/MehdiJaiem/MasterThesis/KnowledgeGraphsGNN/ModelTraining/models.py in __init__(self, kg_triples_data_path, kg_triples_literals_path, kg_embedding_model, kg_random_seed, kg_saved_model_path, logger)
    210                 "No saved model available. Creating knowledge graph model..."
    211             )
--> 212             self.kg_embedding_model = self.create_embedding_model()
    213 
    214     def create_embedding_model(

/home/csc-e-in/workspace/MehdiJaiem/MasterThesis/KnowledgeGraphsGNN/ModelTraining/models.py in create_embedding_model(self, kg_training_loop, kg_neg_sampler, kg_batch_size, kg_number_epochs)
    238             negative_sampler=kg_neg_sampler,
    239             training_loop=kg_training_loop,
--> 240             random_seed=self.kg_random_seed,
    241         )
    242 

/home/ml_in_pp/virtualenvs/KG_MEHDI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pykeen/pipeline/api.py in pipeline(dataset, dataset_kwargs, training, testing, validation, evaluation_entity_whitelist, evaluation_relation_whitelist, model, model_kwargs, interaction, interaction_kwargs, dimensions, loss, loss_kwargs, regularizer, regularizer_kwargs, optimizer, optimizer_kwargs, clear_optimizer, lr_scheduler, lr_scheduler_kwargs, training_loop, training_loop_kwargs, negative_sampler, negative_sampler_kwargs, epochs, training_kwargs, stopper, stopper_kwargs, evaluator, evaluator_kwargs, evaluation_kwargs, result_tracker, result_tracker_kwargs, metadata, device, random_seed, use_testing_data, evaluation_fallback, filter_validation_when_testing, use_tqdm)
   1239         stopper=stopper_instance,
   1240         clear_optimizer=clear_optimizer,
-> 1241         **training_kwargs,
   1242     )
   1243     assert losses is not None  # losses is only none if it's doing search mode

/home/ml_in_pp/virtualenvs/KG_MEHDI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pykeen/training/training_loop.py in train(self, triples_factory, num_epochs, batch_size, slice_size, label_smoothing, sampler, continue_training, only_size_probing, use_tqdm, use_tqdm_batch, tqdm_kwargs, stopper, sub_batch_size, num_workers, clear_optimizer, checkpoint_directory, checkpoint_name, checkpoint_frequency, checkpoint_on_failure, drop_last, callbacks, callback_kwargs, gradient_clipping_max_norm, gradient_clipping_norm_type, gradient_clipping_max_abs_value, pin_memory)
    367                 gradient_clipping_max_abs_value=gradient_clipping_max_abs_value,
    368                 triples_factory=triples_factory,
--> 369                 pin_memory=pin_memory,
    370             )
    371 

/home/ml_in_pp/virtualenvs/KG_MEHDI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pykeen/training/training_loop.py in _train(self, triples_factory, num_epochs, batch_size, slice_size, label_smoothing, sampler, continue_training, only_size_probing, use_tqdm, use_tqdm_batch, tqdm_kwargs, stopper, sub_batch_size, num_workers, save_checkpoints, checkpoint_path, checkpoint_frequency, checkpoint_on_failure_file_path, best_epoch_model_file_path, last_best_epoch, drop_last, callbacks, callback_kwargs, gradient_clipping_max_norm, gradient_clipping_norm_type, gradient_clipping_max_abs_value, pin_memory)
    486             # return the relevant parameters slice_size and batch_size
    487             sub_batch_size, slice_size = self.sub_batch_and_slice(
--> 488                 batch_size=batch_size, sampler=sampler, triples_factory=triples_factory
    489             )
    490 

/home/ml_in_pp/virtualenvs/KG_MEHDI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pykeen/training/training_loop.py in sub_batch_and_slice(self, batch_size, sampler, triples_factory)
    912             batch_size=batch_size,
    913             sub_batch_size=sub_batch_size,
--> 914             supports_sub_batching=supports_sub_batching,
    915         )
    916         return sub_batch_size, slice_size

/home/ml_in_pp/virtualenvs/KG_MEHDI/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pykeen/training/slcwa.py in _slice_size_search(self, triples_factory, batch_size, sub_batch_size, supports_sub_batching)
    133             report = "This model doesn't support sub-batching and slicing is not possible for sLCWA"
    134         logger.warning(report)
--> 135         raise MemoryError("The current model can't be trained on this hardware with these parameters.")

MemoryError: The current model can't be trained on this hardware with these parameters.
```

Why is it not working, although a colleague of mine used the same code 2 years ago?